# Take One Column and Produce Two Sums On One Row

Tags: sql, oracle

Extremely simplified, I have a column of numbers and a column of dates.  I would like to produce one row that sums the numbers based one date into one column and the other date into another column.

The data looks like this -

```
date      number
201111    500
201111    500
201111    500
201109    500
```

I would like it to look like this -

```
sum1    sum 2
1500      500
```

The code I'm using:

```
SELECT SUM(A1.COL1),SUM(A2.COL1)
FROM TAB1 A1,TAB1 A2
WHERE A1.DATE = '201111'
AND A2.DATE = '201109'
```

The results that I get are -

```
sum1    sum2
1000    1500
```

Basically, it's not summing all of sum1 enough (should be 1500 but is returning 1000) and it's summing sum2 too much (should be 500 but is returning 1500).

Comment: Are you sure your query is what you want from a join perspective? Your query will associate every row from Tab1 with itself (100 rows in Tab1 will produce 100x100 rows that will be summed).

Comment: Start by getting rid of the implicit syntax. You have a cross join right now. There is no reason to ever use implicit syntax and as your problem has shown, it should be avoided as it causes errors. Please do not ever use this poor syntax again. Learn to use explicit joins.

Comment: What is your version of oracle?

Answer (score 8):

You probably want something like

```
SELECT SUM( case when date = '201111' then col1 else null end ) sum1,
       SUM( case when date = '201109' then col1 else null end ) sum2
  FROM tab1
 WHERE date in ('201109', '201111')
```

Of course, you should really consider storing dates in `DATE` columns rather than in `VARCHAR2` columns.

Comment: Thank you, I did something like this and it worked fine.  Unfortunately, I figured it out before I read your post. Also, just FYI, the dates aren't true dates but codes for a period of time longer than one month but shorter than one year.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PIVOT too if in 11g

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT date, sum(number) number
    FROM Tab1 
    GROUP BY date)
     PIVOT ( sum(number)  FOR date IN ('201109', '201111') );
```